# MetricsWebClientFilterFunction class is not working in Springboot 3.1.0-RELEASE version

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-form

MetricsWebClientFilterFunction this class is working fine in springboot before 3.0.0 release but it is not working in springboot after 3.0.1 release .
Not able to find alternate class for this in springboot 3.0.1 release or higher versions.

below is my code in spring boot 2.7.2 release version. I want to convert below code into  springboot 3.0.1 release version.

```
MetricsWebClientFilterFunction metricsWebClientFilterFunction = new MetricsWebClientFilterFunction(registry, new ClientRequestObservationContext(), "packetExtractorMetrics", new AutoTimeProperties());
```

Need help from Spring developers or microservice developers on the metrics related to issue.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Duplicating the text in your post doesn't add any clarity.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

MetricsWebClientFilterFunction is removed from Springboot 3, you have to use the new [Observation API](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3).

Some hints for the migration: [GitHub example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34009).